# How to install magento2 sample module?

Tags: magento-2.1

How can I install sample-module-payment-gateway (https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) using composer?

I'm getting error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.", apparently the package name is not recognised.

The documentation only says, that the component should be included in composer, but the how-to is missing?

To clarify: I'm not interested in sample data, but a sample module.

Comment: Can you please update question with composer.json code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, sample modules doesn't allow to be installed via composer.
But [new documentation](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/54509f96710e2bd63955dd1c7502235c52744338/sample-module-custom-deployment-config/README.md#install) describes how you can install it with git cloning.

Comment: Thank you.
Actually, I ended up doing  the same on my own.

In the master branch readme.md it says: "This module is intended to be installed using composer. " If it is not possible to use composer to install, this is perfectly in line with other Magento documentation.

Comment: The main readme is outdated, we are using git to works with sample modules. @TeroLahtinen, if the answer solves your problem, please, accept it.